# What's managing the git I'm using on my mac?

Tags: macos, git, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm confused on what's managing the `git` I'm using given my environment. I'm using:

- GitHub UI with [command line tools installed](https://github.com/blog/1510-installing-git-from-github-for-mac)
- Homebrew

Xcode is not installed at this time but may have been in the past. I'm running 10.10.1 of OS X.

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ brew upgrade git
Error: git-2.1.3 already installed
$ git --version
git version 1.8.4
$ pip show git
$
```

*To clarify my goal:* I'd accept removing the 1.8.4 version of `git` in favor of the later version managed through `brew` if and only if it doesn't break the native GitHub app.

Comment: What is the output of `which git`? Also whats the output of `echo $PATH`? And where does bomebrew normally install its packages? Most likely you just need to adjust your path.

Comment: Commands run and added to question. I'm not sure on the path of homebrew though @prodigitalson.

Comment: It's `/usr/local`, which UI apps don't natively pick up. The homebrew site [isn't updated for Yosemite](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#faq) so I'd like to confirm before I make an edit.

Comment: Yeah /usr/local isn't going to change and not have docs updated immediately since that would be a HUGE change. Did you upgrade your system? I think Homebrew checks to see if there is a native bin installed already. Its likely that Yosimite came with that version of Git... you could confirm by checking if there is a version in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` and then running `git --version` with the full path like `/usr/bin/git --version` If it reports that 2.1.3 version Homebrew is complianing about then you have your answer, just remove the one from `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Wow, there's a third copy: `$ /usr/bin/git --version \ git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`. What's the smartest move here? Ignore the other versions, change path and stick w/homebrews version?

Comment: What versions exist in /usr/local/Cellar/git? If both 1.8.4 and 2.1.3 are there, try running `brew unlink git` then `brew link git`. Furthermore, according to [the release notes](https://mac.github.com/release-notes.html), current GitHub UI uses a newer version of Git than 1.8.4.

Comment: @JeffreyPfau the Cellar shows 2.1.3; same as the command output. Only one version. I have `git-flow` installed too if that's relevant.

Comment: `brew link git --overwrite` will replace the version in /usr/local with Homebrew's.

Comment: Woot! @TimSmith that did what I hoped to achieve! Could you answer the question so I can mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew link git --overwrite` will replace the version in /usr/local with Homebrew's. Homebrew is shy about overwriting files; if /usr/local/bin/git already existed before you ran `brew install git`, Homebrew would have built and installed git to the Cellar but wouldn't have symlinked the Homebrew git into /usr/local.

The Xcode/CLT git is in /usr/bin.